# Is CORS required for SEO?

Tags: seo, cross-origin

I have created a web application and I want the website to optimized for Search Engines. So, do i need to provide Cross Origin Resource Sharing functionality within my site in order to allow the search engines to read text from my site and display in search results ?

Comment: Why would you think you need this?

Comment: @JohnConde I didn't knew how SEO works on search engine side, therefore i thought that they may need CORS to access the site content otherwise my site would not allow their site to fetch content from my site. But my site would still be accessible through browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is for when a website instructs browser to fetch data from another site.  That isn't how search engines implement search results.  Search engines send robot spiders to crawl and index your site.  During this process the text from your pages is copied to them search engine servers. Search engines use their local copy of your page to put a snippet into the search results.  They don't have to have the browser fetch it from your site dynamically.

There is no need to implement CORS for SEO.